# Collecting Links from Multiple Pages with QueryPath

Tags: php, arrays, querypath

I have a functon that is passed an array of url's. Each webpage will have a series of links to other pages. I want to return a complete list of these links from every webpage passed to this function. I'm stuck at how to combine the array at each loop.

```
 function getitemurls ($pagelinks) {
 global $host;
 foreach($pagelinks as $link) {
   $circdl = my_curl($link);
   $circqp = htmlqp($circdl,'body');
   $circlinks = array();
   foreach ($circqp->branch()->top('area[href]') as $item) {
   $circlinks[] = $item->attr('href');
    }
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($circlinks); ++$i) {
   $fullitemurl = join(array($host,$circlinks[$i]));
   }
    }
  return $fullitemurl;
 }
```

For example:

```
 Webpage 1: page1.html
 <html><body><area shape="rect" href="http://www.google.com" coords="110,151,173,225" alt=""/></body></html>

 Webpage 2: page2.html
      <html><body><area shape="rect" href="http://www.yahoo.com" coords="110,151,173,225" alt=""/></body></html>
```

Here is the array of the two pages:

```
 $array = array (
"0" => "page1.html",
"1" => "page2.html", );
```

From this array I would like to return:

```
 getitemurls($array)
 Array ( [0] => http://www.google.com [1] => http://www.yahoo.com)
```

Comment: Figure it out: just declared $fullitemurl as an array before the loop. Works great now!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just declaring my array before the loop and then assigning it as such in the loop:

```
 function getitemurls ($pagelinks) {
  global $host;
  $fullitemurls = array();
  foreach($pagelinks as $link) {
   $circdl = my_curl($link);
   $circqp = htmlqp($circdl,'body');
   $circlinks = array();
   foreach ($circqp->branch()->top('area[href]') as $item) {
    $circlinks[] = $item->attr('href');
   }
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($circlinks); ++$i) {
    $fullitemurl[] = join(array($host,$circlinks[$i]));
   }
  }
 return $fullitemurl;
}
```